# Managing users data in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, authsub

I'm writing some Google App Egnine + Android service for self and my friends.
For each user this service will ask AuthSub token for another Google services. 
And by cron will retrieve information from this services and send it via c2dm on their cell phones.

I need somewhere store user information and auth sub token for use it from cron.
And if I understand correctly google app engine already has libs for this goal.
Could you show me right direction for research (manuals, examples):
- how to store auth sub token (I got it from gdata api);
- how to retrieve it with google user id;
- how to obtain all users data in cron jobs;

PS: I'm c++ developer and it my first web app, sorry if this question is newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to store information in app-engine you need to use the [Datastore](http://code.google.com/intl/el/appengine/docs/python/datastore/).

See [here](http://code.google.com/intl/el/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html) of an example. You probably need to create a model with two string properties, the google id and the auth token.

Comment: Thanks. This way is works. I just had a hope that app engine had special utilities to manage accounts and tokens.